# React: How to Keep Accordion Entry Expanded After Remount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, accordion

I have an accordion style `<EndpointList />` component consisting of several `<Endpoint />` components. Every `<Endpoint />` has a parameter section that is initially hidden and that is expanded when the user clicks that endpoint's header.

My goal is that when an `<Endpoint />` is expanded and the user navigates to some other view and then comes back to the view containing the list of endpoints, the `<Endpoint />` that was expanded before should still be expanded. That is, its parameter section should still be visible even when the whole `<EndpointList />` was unmounted and remounted in the meantime.

Each endpoint has a boolean `expanded` flag indicating whether its parameters are currently expanded or not. I achieved my goal by moving these flags out of the `<Endpoint />` and `<EndpointList />` components into my top level component that never gets remounted. However, this introduces the following new problems:

1. If I understand React correctly, the whole `<EndpointList />` is now re-rendered whenever an endpoint is expanded or collapsed, as this changes my top level component's state which is passed down to the `<EndpointList />`. Correct? (There is a noticable delay when expanding endpoints in a list that contains a lot of them)
2. A single endpoint might be contained in multiple `<EndpointList />` components throughout my application. With my current approach, when an endpoint is expanded, it is expanded everywhere it occurs in the application, not just in the `<EndpointList />` instance where its header was actually clicked. I obviously don't want this behavior.

So my questions are:

- What is a good way to maintain an endpoint's `expanded` state and to not lose it when the component displaying the endpoint is remounted?
- If moving the `expanded` state up in the component hierarchy (as I did) is the best (or the only) way to achieve this, how do I get rid of the problems described above?

Thanks in advance!

---

**Update:** I created a JSFiddle to illustrate the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/7shLogek/2. You can actually see in your browser console that every endpoint list gets re-rendered whenever an endpoint is expanded or collapsed. Also, the endpoints are obviously always expanded/collapsed in both lists at the same time.

---

**Update 2:** I solved the performance issue (1.) by implementing `Endpoint.shouldComponentUpdate()` and using [Facebook's Shallow Compare Addon](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/shallow-compare.html) so that only those endpoints that have actually changed are re-rendered.

Comment: are you using flux in your component ?

Comment: Nope, not using Flux.

Comment: Can u share the fiddle of how you fixed the code?

Answer (score 0):

Some quick tips:

- 1: If you can`t get the remounting performant enough, try hiding and
  showing the root component if possible, instead of remounting.
- 2: I notice that you input the same state to each of the lists, you
  probably need to create a collection of states for the EndpointList
  (like you have with this.state.endpoints) to have individual
  behaviour for each list.

Comment: Thanks for your tips. I fixed the performance issue already, see my update in the question.

Regarding your second suggestion, I also think that this is the only way to go for me. Somebody else gave me the same answer.